# What are unique UI controls on Android?

Tags: layout, controls, android, conventions

Apart from regular UI controls like tabview and listview, are there any unique and attractive UI controls like Quick action bar, Action bar, or iOS spinner (Date and time selector) which are attractive to use on Android?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, I have found a few that I think are good looking and have decent UX as well:

- [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/)
- [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)
- [android-actionbar](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/)

Out of those I like GreenDroid the best. I hope these help you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the [DroidUX](http://www.droidux.com) UI component library.

[DroidUX](http://www.droidux.com) is the first professional UI/UX component library for Android.  It includes widgets like ActionBar/AppBar, Dashboard, QuickActions, Wheel 3D Carousel, DateTimePicker, Editor, and other unique and visually appealing widgets.

You can see it in action, by downloading the [API Demos](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.droidux.components.demo) app in the Android Market.

You can also try the library FREE [here](http://www.droidux.com/download).

Comment: Note: [Ricky Lee is the founder](http://droidux.com/company/about-us/item/about-us) of the company making DroidUX.

Comment: Yes, I am the founder and creator of the DroidUX component library.  Thanks @Rahul for noting :-)